# chrome bug on mac with retina display?

Tags: css, google-chrome, retina

I just wanna drawing the diagonal lines with css3 for this:

http://bq.yunqi.li/puzzle/sudoku/sudoku-x.php

it works fine on chrome/firefox/safari on every platform.

But when the case came to CHROME on Macbook with RETINA display, it just messed up.

After some research I found a very strange thing that chrome on retina renders 1px-width border as 1px and n p as (n-1) px. (n>1).

I think that was the issue. So maybe that's a bug? And is there any solution?

I tried chrome 27/28(which is the latest till now), they gave me the same thing.

Environment: Mac OS X 10.8.4 on 13" Macbook with retina display, Chrome 28.0.1500.71.

Many thanks.

Comment: Looks Ok for me on Chrome 30 on a 15" rMBP.

Comment: sorry I just forgot a thing that when the width of the input of a cell was not multiple of 5, the width/height chrome on retina rendered would be a very long floating number.(See the Metrics) And then it goes to be not squared, then messed things up. I modified the width/height of the input to 48px(which was the real case). Try to check it again and see the difference between Safari and Chrome shows.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because user made a mistake and question is not relevant any more.

Answer (score 0):

Oh that was my fault. I didn't remember that I ZOOMED a page at this site to 90% months ago...

Now it's OK.